# jquery data attribute selector with set of values

Tags: jquery, html, object, jquery-plugins, selector

My problem is how to select object with specific data value using jQuery `data()`? For example:

```
$('[data-infos-parent_id=0]').html('it ok');
```

```html
<div class="question" data-infos='{"parent_id":0,"my_id":0, "title":""}'>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) here, [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) will fetch the arbitrary data stored with element and it will try to convert it appropriate data type.

```
$('.question[data-infos]').filter(function(){
   return $(this).data('infos')["parent_id"] == 0;
}).html('it ok');
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could access a json object saved in a data attribute directly without parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/w1paL17d/

```
$('.question').each(function(){
    var json = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-infos'));
    if(json.parent_id === 0){
        $(this).html('it ok');
    }
});
```

Comment: think you for all

Comment: Code dump is not useful to novice users. You should always try to explain the changes which and why you did.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `html()` function

```
$('.question').html(function(){
    var json = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-infos'));
    if(json.parent_id === 0){
        return 'it ok';
    }
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/4koq5uzx/